# Can (and should) methods be redeclared with different parameters in PHP7?

Tags: php, oop, methods, parameters, php-7

I'm in the process of modernizing a steaming pile of legacy PHP4 code. I'm not extremely well versed in OOP (yet) but I'm stuck with the job.

In the old PHP4 code I have the following:

```
class theParent {
  function greet () {
    return "Good morning";
  }
}

class theChild extends theParent {
  function greet ($inDaHood = FALSE) {
    if ($inDaHood)
      return "Yo! What up?\n";
    else
      return "Hello\n";
  }
}
```

In the child class the greet() method is redeclared with different parameters than the original greet() method in the parent class. This was fine in PHP4 (which was essentially a free-for-all; it didn't even have private methods). It also works in PHP7 without generating any erors.

But is this stillrecommended) in PHP7? Or is there now a more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. You are simply overloading/overriding/whatever-PHP-calls-it the `greet` method. In fact, the only common feature the two methods share is the name; as far as PHP is concerned they are two different things.

Comment: However, PHP7 does issue a warning: Declaration of theChild::greet ($inDaHood = FALSE) should be compatible with theParent::greet () in theFile.php on line 12345. This suggests that this practice may cause issues  in future PHP versions and therefore should be discouraged.